# Cant start docker containers from Docker Desktop in Mac

Tags: macos, docker-desktop

I've used docker desktop in Linux and Windows without problem, but i recently got a mac, and when i try to start a docker container i have setup via Docker Desktop, the docker container starts, but immediately just changes from "Running" to "exited" status.

This doesnt happen in the other environments i use docker, so any help would be appreciated.

I have been trying to find any kind of logs, but i cant find any.

im using mac os x 11.7.1 (Big Sur)
Docker desktop is the newest version 4.16.2

I have tried so far:

Reinstalling Docker Desktop
verified and ensured the permissions for access to docker are set correctly (access to files and folders)
I have setup my dockerhub account
Im using the latests versions of the php and python images available at docker hub.

Thank you.

Comment: You can inspect the log in the **view details** option in Containers tab(found in the 3 dot option on the right hand side of your container)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately nothing appears on this screen.